# Batch to find and copy folders from textlist

Tags: batch-file, copy, find, directory, subdirectory

I'm looking for batch to find and copy all folders listed in textfile to specifed location.

For example a have:

1. Textfile.txt wit content:

   - 01
   - 02
   - 03
   - 04
   - etc.
2. Head folder with subfolders.

Folders which I'm looking for (folders from Textfile.txt) can be placed in every subfolder.
If I want to find and copy folders from Textfile.txt to specifed location. I need to serch all subfolders from head folder

Example folders tree

1. Home folder

   - Subfolders (11st, 12st, 13st...)
   - Folders (01, 02, 03, 04,)

Please help me with construction that batch. Thanks.

**Additional informations:**

```
- Home folder (head folder)
  - John (folder)
    - 01 (folder) (can be blank, without any folders and files)
      - 11st (folder) (can be blank, without any folders and files)
        - file1.txt (files)
        - file2.xls
      - 12st
      - 13st
    - 02
    - 03
    - 04
  - Thomas
    - 05
      - 11st
      - 12st
      - 13st
    - 06
  - Ewa
  - Martin
    - 07
      - 11st
      - 12st
      - 15st
  - George
    - 08
```

I need to find and copy entire folders 01, 02, 03, 04, etc. from Textfile.txt even if are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work in batch file:

```
FOR /F %%F IN (Textfile.txt) DO xcopy /I /E "C:\Source\%%F" "D:\Dest\%%F"
```

You can apply some more switches as well:

```
  /C           Continues copying even if errors occur.
  /H           Copies hidden and system files also.
  /R           Overwrites read-only files.
  /Y           Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an
               existing destination file.
```

**Update**

In your specific case when you have list of folders that scattered across subfolders this script should work:

```
@echo off

set SRC_FOLDER="C:\Source"
set DST_FOLDER="C:\Destination"

REM this makes sure that if the first folder in list is empty - it is copied 
IF NOT EXIST %DST_FOLDER% MKDIR %DST_FOLDER%

REM loop through the items in list; use one per line 
REM for group match use <NAME>*
FOR /f %%F IN (%~dp0\Textfile.txt) DO (
   REM loop through all folders
   FOR /f "delims=" %%D IN ('DIR %SRC_FOLDER% /A:D /B') DO (
       REM loop through FOLDER/NAME* sub-folders
       FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D\%%F" /A:D /B') DO (
          IF EXIST %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D\%%G" XCOPY /I /E %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D\%%G" %DST_FOLDER%\"%%~nG"
       )
       REM loop through all FOLDER subfolders to catch NAME subfolders 
       FOR /f "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D" /A:D /B') DO (
          IF "%%G" == "%%F" XCOPY /I /E %SRC_FOLDER%\"%%D\%%G" %DST_FOLDER%\"%%~nG"
       )
   )
)
```

- Note that "delims=" parameter is needed to correct handling of paths with spaces.`enter code here`

Comment: I tried this but it works only if all folders are in one direstory. Ift didnt work if folders are in subdir.

Comment: @Artec OK, I thought you specify all folders relative to one root folder... but it turned out you need to find also . Then, the question - do you need to replicate folder structure in destination folder, if not - what if two folders found in source with the same name?

Comment: Theoretically it is not possible for example that JOHN and EWA has folder nr 01.

Comment: I have a lot of private folders with names: John, Ewa, George...they are gathering data with the same structure,only difference is in subfolder name. Your code works good if folders 01, 02, 03...etc are all placed in root folder. I need the way to place them to the root folder and than copy from textlist to specifed folder.

Comment: pmod@ When I run it as admin I see "can't find Textfile.txt". If I add  pushd "%~dp0" on the top or full path to the "Textfile.txt" it works.But If I have in John folder for example 100 folders 01, 02...100 and in "Textfile.txt" I have only 01 It still copy all 100 folders. This process is needn't. Is it possible to copy only this folders from list ?

Comment: @Artec no, you shouldn't add full path to Textfile, where it is located?

Comment: Its located in the same folder than batch file. Without pushd "%~dp0" on the script top its error - "System can't find Textfile.txt"

Comment: I have only one last question for the content of Textfile.txt. How to find all folders which starts 01. For example 01, 01_2013-10-25, 01-2013-10-26 ? Is it possible to use some special symbols in Textfile.txt like 01* or something like this ?

Comment: @Artec Check my new update, you should be able to copy all starting with 01 using 01*

Comment: pmod@ I've checked it, and it works. Problem is only when home folder has strange name with symbols and spaces - example: !!! Home folder 2013 Październik. I tried to change encoding with notepad+ on (OEM852) but without result. Localy with standard names it works properly. Thank You very much for help. If you have any idea for resolving this I will be so glad. PMOD - Thanks a lot one more time.

Comment: @Artec Yes it was some known issue (for /d - doesn't work with spaces in path)... I fixed it with some tricky solution, now it should work now. You upvote answer if you want :)

Comment: pmod@ That it's what I need and what I'm looking for. Before reading Your answer I have changed folders names and make a job with your first script. Now I'm checking this new one and "I have no  question".  Of course I'll try to upvote your script. Thank You.